# Using BibLaTeX, how to cite an article with an appendix written by someone other than the author?

Tags: biblatex

Let's say that I want to cite an article (or a book or whatever) written by a set of authors, which contains an appendix written by a different set of authors. The entry could look somewhat like this:

> A. Author and B. Author. With an appendix by C. Author. "The Theory of theories." In: J. Journal 1234.5 (2020), pp. 10–20.

I know that I could just add a note field with the content "With an appendix by C. Author", but it wouldn't get localized correctly, the author of the appendix would have to be formatted by hand, etc. How would I go about representing that in BibLaTeX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to [pst](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/48251/pst)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/551708/35864), but using the name `editora`, whose exact role can be specified in `editoratype`. Just set a useful `<typestring>` and define the string `by<typestring>` for the output.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\NewBibliographyString{bywithappendix}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  withappendix   = {appendix},
  withappendixs  = {appendix},
  bywithappendix = {with an appendix by},
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{example,
  author      = {Athor, Anne and Author, Berta},
  editora     = {Author, Claudia},
  editoratype = {withappendix},
  title       = {The Theory of Theories},
  journal     = {J. Journal},
  date        = {2020},
  volume      = {1234},
  number      = {5},
  pages       = {10-20},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{example}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Anne Athor and Berta Author. “The Theory of Theories”. In: J. Journal 1234.5 (2020). With an appendix by Claudia Author, pp. 10–20.]

---

Alternatively, you can use the `related` functionality, where you would essentially create a separate container for the appendix, which is then called by the main article.

In the example below the appendix entry only contains the `author` and the setup only prints the author, but that can be extended to more fields if that would be useful.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\NewBibliographyString{appendix,by}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  appendix = {with an appendix},
  by       = {by},
}

\newbibmacro*{related:appendix}[1]{%
  \entrydata{#1}{%
    \bibstring{by}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \printnames{author}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{example,
  author      = {Athor, Anne and Author, Berta},
  title       = {The Theory of Theories},
  journal     = {J. Journal},
  date        = {2020},
  volume      = {1234},
  number      = {5},
  pages       = {10-20},
  related     = {example:appendix},
  relatedtype = {appendix},
}
@misc{example:appendix,
  author     = {Author, Claudia},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{example}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Anne Athor and Berta Author. “The Theory of Theories”. In: J. Journal 1234.5 (2020), pp. 10–20. With an appendix by Claudia Author.]

Answer (score 1):

There are several fields in Biblatex for various parts of a work. I think the closest to an "appendix" is "afterword".

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[abbreviate=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{withapp.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{example}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

@Article{example,
  author =   {Author, A. and Author, B.},
  afterword =    {Author, C.},
  title =    {The Theory of Theories},
  journal =      {J. Journal},
  year =     2020,
  volume =   1234,
  number =   5,
  pages =    {10-20}}
```

[image]

If "afterword" is not good enough, just change it yourself. I think we shouldn't ask for many more kinds of parts to be added, because there are so many strings to handle for translations for Biblatex already.